# Creating active record association from json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, activerecord

I currently have the following associations in my model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :departments
end
```

and

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I already have some users in my database and the users table has the column company_code which is a unique to each user.

Instead of assigning a user first,

```
@user = User.where(company_code: "11111").first
@user.departments.create([{"name":"General","company_code":"11111"},{"name":"Sales","company_code":"11111"}])
```

I would like to know if it is possible to create Departments from the array below which fetches the user by the company_code when creating the record.

```
[{
    "name": "General",
    "company_code": "11111"
},
{
    "name": "Sales",
    "company_code": "11111"
},
{
    "name": "General",
    "company_code": "22222"
},
{
    "name": "Sales",
    "company_code": "22222"
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your array is values

```
values.each do |value|
  User.where(company_code: value["company_code"]).first.departments.create(value)
end
```